# Problem with rotation a camera with the mouse OPENGL GLFW

Tags: opengl, c++, camera, glfw

I am trying to move my camera with my mouse, I can translate it juste by changing the current position of my camera, but when I want to move my forward vector and my up vector of my camera it doesnt work very well, the camera seem to move whereas it's not the case...

```
void Camera::moveCameraRotateUpdtade(GLFWwindow * window)
{


 //curseur mvt ...
  double xpos, ypos;
  Vec3f new_front;
  std::cout << "front = " << CameraFront << std::endl;

  glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
  if(!(xpos > _width-1 || xpos < 0) && !(ypos > _height-1 || ypos < 0))
  {
    float x = (2.0f * xpos) / _width - 1.0f;
    float y = 1.0f - (2.0f * ypos) / _height;

horizontalAngle += mouseSpeed  * float(x) ;
verticalAngle   -= mouseSpeed  * float(y) ;


std::cout << "x y = " << x << " " << y << std::endl;
std::cout << "horizontalAngle verticalAngle = " << horizontalAngle << " " << verticalAngle << std::endl;


new_front = Vec3f(cos(verticalAngle) * sin(horizontalAngle),sin(verticalAngle),cos(verticalAngle) * cos(horizontalAngle));
Vec3f right = Vec3f(sin(horizontalAngle - M_PI/2.0f),0.0,cos(horizontalAngle - M_PI/2.0f));
CameraUp = right.cross(new_front);
CameraUp = CameraUp.normalize();
CameraFront = new_front.normalize();

std::cout << "CameraFront = " << CameraFront;
std::cout << "CameraUp = " << CameraUp;
std::cout << "position = " << _positionCam;

LookAt( _positionCam + CameraFront,_positionCam, CameraUp);
}

}
```

Here my lookAt function :

```
Mat4f Camera::LookAt(Vec3f target, Vec3f position,Vec3f CameraUp)
{
  //ce dont j'ai besoin pour calculer les parametre de ma camera...
  Vec3f f = (target - position).normalize();
  Vec3f u = CameraUp.normalize();
  Vec3f s = f.cross(u).normalize();
  u = s.cross(f);

  Mat4f R;
  R.setCol(0,s);
  R.setCol(1,u);
  Vec3f f_tmp = f*-1.0 ;
  R.setCol(2,f_tmp);
  R.setElement(0,3,-1.0f * s.dot(position));
  R.setElement(1,3,-1.0f * u.dot(position));
  R.setElement(2,3,f.dot(position));
  _LookAt = R.transpose();

  return  _LookAt;

}
```

Here a video showing my problem :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am_1sfMQllQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix my bug,it was in the implementation of my lookAt function :

```
Mat4f Camera::LookAt(Vec3f target, Vec3f position,Vec3f CameraUp)
{
  //ce dont j'ai besoin pour calculer les parametre de ma camera...
  Vec3f f = (target - position).normalize();
  Vec3f u = CameraUp.normalize();
  Vec3f s = f.cross(u).normalize();
  //u = s.cross(f);

  Mat4f R;
  R.setCol(0,s);
  R.setCol(1,u);
  Vec3f f_tmp = f*-1.0 ;
  R.setCol(2,f_tmp);
  Mat4f T;
  position = position *-1.0f;
  T.setCol(3,position);
  R = R * T;

  /*
  R.setElement(0,3,-1.0f * s.dot(position));
  R.setElement(1,3,-1.0f * u.dot(position));
  R.setElement(2,3,f.dot(position));*/
  _LookAt = R.transpose();

  return  _LookAt;

}
```